# Solidity: Burn event vs Transfer to 0 address

Tags: solidity

I've seen the Burn event be represented as:

- `Burn(burner, _value);` in [OpenZeppelin's BurnableToken](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/token/BurnableToken.sol)
- `Transfer(_owner, 0, _amount);` in [Giveth's MiniMeToken](https://github.com/Giveth/minime/blob/master/contracts/MiniMeToken.sol)

Are both of these ways correct?
Is one of these ways better than the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [ERC 20 standard](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/20) doesn't mention burning specifically, as far as I can see. It does, however, specify the Transfer event as:

```
event Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint256 _value)
```

So to be compatible with any software that meets the standard, Transfer is what you want.